# PhanthomJS , execute script and return value from Js to c#

Tags: c#, phantomjs

I need to return a value from a javascript script to c# using PhantomJS.
This time, from AngularJS, but, 
¿Can PhantomJS return a javascript value from a evaluated script?

I can do it with Awesowium with

```
webViewBrowser.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult
```

but there is a way with PhantomJS?

Example (Not working)

```
var saldos=driver.ExecutePhantomJS("var strValue=JSON.stringify($('#accounts').scope().accounts);");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just adding "**return**" on your script or function. 
Also, remove ExecutePhantomJS and use ExecuteScript

```
var accounts=driver.ExecuteScript("return JSON.stringify($('#accounts').scope().accounts);");
```